# Azure Search Updating Individual Documents

Tags: azure-cognitive-search

We are using Azure Search for various scenarios. We often need to update an individual document with changes that users make. We need to have these changes become visible in our indexes as soon as possible so that the stale time is as short as possible within reason.

What is the best strategy to handle this. We know that batch updates is the way to go but we need more immediate reflection of the changes.

Once a document is updated, how long does it take for the index to reflect this change.

Many thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If the updates are not very frequent, you can simply update the Azure Search document immediately (that is, using batches of size 1). On the other hand, if the updates are extremely frequent and you notice a high rate of failures with single-document batches, you will need to build some sort of "collector" mechanism to batch up updates. My recommendation would be to do the simple thing first: try single-document batches, and add batching logic if necessary.

Updated or newly indexed documents are reflected in the search results after a short delay, usually ranging from single milliseconds to 1-2 seconds. The delay depends on the service topology and indexing load.

Comment: Shvets Many thanks for you prompt response. You mention a "High Rate of Failures". Is that update failures? Could this Happen that a document does not get updated after updating it. Is there a recommended error handling example we can look at.

Comment: Correct, I was referring to failures of your calls to Azure Search to index/update documents. If Index operation returns success, then all documents will be (eventually) updated. If it returns 503 HTTP status, retry with back-off. If it returns 207 status, some but not all of the documents were indexed; response tells you which documents failed, retry only those. If you're using our .NET SDK, a lot of these details are baked into the SDK.

Comment: Many Thanks. This is great help. We are using the SDK - does this mean that these failure scenarios are AUTOMATICALLY taken care of by the SDK. i.e to retry and which documents to do that for if failure does occur?

Comment: The SDK retries on 503s. It does not retry on 207s, but provides a helper to construct a new batch containing only the failed documents.