# Can an Azure Search indexer overwrite updates posted through the API?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-cognitive-search

I am writing an application where we synchronize updates to our data by calling the Azure Search API with batches of one element (as explained in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/39067128/2110623)). As a backup we have a [search indexer](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) that runs once an hour. That way, if updating the index through the API fails or if we forget to trigger it in our code, the changes will eventually be synced to the search index.

**My question is**: is it possible that the search indexer overwrites an API update as in the scenario below?

1. The search indexer copies a row from the database
2. The application updates the same row in the database, which is then synced to the search index by an API call
3. The search indexer updates the document in the index based on the outdated  copy of the data

Comment: Is your "search indexer" a custom task which fetches and also sends the record via the Azure Search Api?

Comment: The search indexer is an azure-specific mechanism that detects database changes and updates the index. It is not part of my application. I just updated the question with a link to the [docs](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/search/search-howto-connecting-azure-sql-database-to-azure-search-using-indexers) to make it clearer

Comment: Although I have no specific knowledge I'm pretty sure this is possible. To avoid this issue Azure would need to lock the index data and the database data at the same time and then update the index before releasing the locks. It is unlikely that the system is implemented that way. Distributed locks are very brittle.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, it's certainly possible to have a race condition between indexer updating a document and API call updating a document. You can mitigate this by postponing your API updates until after an indexer has finished running, or by using just one mechanism (indexer *or* API).